# Cannot register to background task in JavaScript Windows app

Tags: javascript, windows

I am using Javascript to register a background task. Everything goes ok, but I cannot register.

```
var background = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;                     
var builder = new background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();



builder.Name = "Background Task for Loadshedding App";

builder.TaskEntryPoint = "../js/backgroundTask.js";
builder.setTrigger(hourlyTrigger);                   


var task = builder.register(); //Error points to this line
```

Error: ***0x80040154 - JavaScript runtime error: Class not registered***

Comment: Did you see the Documentation? @tika?

Comment: @selu These are codes from the documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through a lot of documentations, and found it myself and thought of posting so that it might help others:

```
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "backgroundTask.js";
```

And the `entry point` of background task in App Manifest should be: `backgroundTask.js`

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Putting this up for people reaching this page through Google or the like.

If this error pops up, something is wrong with your instance of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder()`. It's incomplete or it has an error in it somewhere.

For example you might have used `builder.Name` instead of `builder.name`, therefore the name attribute is empty and you get an error.

I would add this as a comment, sadly I lack the reputation required.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @LawrenceAiello In fact, this hint could be helpful (although it would be great if there was more detail about the possible error, and how to fix it). I'm not voting for deletion in this case.